# How to Schedule Fixed-Time Cache Revalidation in Next.js 13+ (e.g., Every 6 Hours at 00:00, 06:00, etc.)

Tags: caching, next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js(13+) project where I need to revalidate cached data at fixed times every 6 hours (e.g., at 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, and 18:00) regardless of when the user session started. I understand that Next.js's built-in revalidation works based on the time elapsed since the last generation of the page, but I'm looking for a way to revalidate at these specific times.

##### Requirements:

- Revalidate certain pages or data every 6 hours at fixed times (00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00).
- The revalidation should occur at these exact times, not based on the user's session or last access.

##### What I've Tried:

- I've looked into Next.js's `revalidate` option, but it seems to be based on duration since the last access, rather than fixed times.
- I am considering setting up a server-side cron job to hit a Next.js API route for triggering revalidation, but I'm unsure if this is the most efficient approach.

##### Questions:

1. Is there a built-in feature in Next.js that supports fixed-time revalidation, or do I need to implement a custom solution?
2. If a custom solution is necessary, what would be the best practice to set up a server-side cron job for this purpose in a Next.js environment?
3. Are there any potential pitfalls or considerations I should be aware of when implementing this kind of time-based cache revalidation?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to approach this in an efficient and scalable way.